# Why I can't send broadcast to receiver successfull if Intent was set Type?

Tags: android, android-broadcast, android-broadcastreceiver

I create a receiver and dynamic register it in my app:

```
MyReceiver receiver = new MyReceiver();
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("com.test.receiver");
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);
```

I write some codes as below to sending broadcast, my receiver can recive the  message successull, everything is ok.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("com.test.receiver");
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(MainActivity.this).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

But if I try to setType() for the Intent, my receiver will not work, nothing will be received.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("com.test.receiver");

intent.setType("test");

LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

According to Android API document, Type doesn't have intent-filter function, do you know why?

Comment: The type certainly is considered for the match: [`IntentFilter#match(String action, String type, String scheme, Uri data, Set<String> categories, String logTag)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/IntentFilter.html#match(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.net.Uri,%20java.util.Set%3Cjava.lang.String%3E,%20java.lang.String)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From **[Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent)**, `setType()` method is used to set valid MIME type.

> **setType(String type)**
>
> Set an explicit MIME data type.

Here is common MIME type that you can send.

```
image/jpeg
audio/mpeg4-generic
text/html
audio/mpeg
audio/aac
audio/wav
audio/ogg
audio/midi
audio/x-ms-wma
video/mp4
video/x-msvideo
video/x-ms-wmv
image/png
image/jpeg
image/gif
.xml ->text/xml
.txt -> text/plain
.cfg -> text/plain
.csv -> text/plain
.conf -> text/plain
.rc -> text/plain
.htm -> text/html
.html -> text/html
.pdf -> application/pdf
.apk -> application/vnd.android.package-archive
```

Whereas `test` is not a valid MIME type.